# 'only x left threshold' option not working

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, stock-status

I have set the threshold to 7, I've set a simple product to quantity 2 and manage stock etc is on, it's also in stock. The setting 'Display products availability in stock in the frontend' is set to yes, they're all set correctly on store view/website level etc.

Yet it doesn't display the message, it doesn't even seem to be pulling in the template file that the message is in (cataloginventory/stockqty/default.phtml) although I don't even know how it would pull in this file as it exists in cataloginventory not catalog, also I can't find any reference to it in catalog.xml

Comment: Are you using any custom theme?

Comment: we're using a custom theme inside RWD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like below,

If you open file **app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\cataloginventory.xml**

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <reference name="product.info.simple.extra">
        <block type="cataloginventory/stockqty_default" template="cataloginventory/stockqty/default.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

Here the tag `PRODUCT_TYPE_simple` defines that it is used for simple products. Inside this tag you can find a `reference` tag with name `product.info.simple.extra`
This will check a block with the name `product.info.simple.extra` and add the template file **cataloginventory/stockqty/default.phtml** inside it.

Now, if you search where the block with name `product.info.simple.extra` is defined, you will get your **catalog.xml** file.

If you check **app\design\frontend\rwd\YOUR_THEME\layout\catalog.xml** you will find below code.

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.availability" as="product_type_availability" template="catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml" />
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

Here, you can see the block with name `product.info.simple.extra`
So, the first file **cataloginventory.xml** will add the template to this block.

Please check your **catalog.xml** if you have a block with name `product.info.simple.extra` inside it which is responsible for adding the message on product view page.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I have all this! What is my product phtml file supposed to look like to include this?

Comment: If you check further your catalog xml, you can see that `product.info.simple.extra` block is added in `product.info` which at last get included in `content` section. So you do not need to add anything in phtml file.

Comment: @seanyt123, please also check if your product view page includes **catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml** file by enabling template path hints.

Comment: Thank you! Looking to see if my product view page included that template helped, it did not, I added the line <?php echo ($this->getChildHtml('product_type_data')) ?>